# Performance differences between: JOIN within the same database, JOIN across two databases, JOIN of a database with a linked database (server object)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This spooks my mind and i can't test for another three days, so i might as well ask...

Suppose a standard JOIN statement like this:

```
SELECT 
  names.name
  ,adresses.adress
FROM
  names
JOIN
  adresses
ON
  names.ID=adresses.FK_ID
```

Suppose you want the database engine/optimizer to have this run fast.

Questions: what are the differences in

- query run time
- memory usage
- available SQL Server sotware technology to improve run time

if these cases apply:

1. the two tables are located within the same database
2. the two tables are located in two different databases of the same instance
3. the table "names" is located in my instance, the table "adresses" is in a linked database (server object)

In case 1 my usual strategy to enhance such a queries runtime (other than clearing out dead data/duplicates and cutting down data type lengths to necessity) is building proper indexes and statistics.

If i do so in case 2, would the optimizer be able to take equal advantage of indexes and statistics as in case 1? Would the query plan look similar? Would the run time and memory usage be similar? (I am almost 100% certain it would, have also read this: [What are the problems with a join between two tables in two different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144457/what-are-the-problems-with-a-join-between-two-tables-in-two-different-databases))

In case 3 obviously there would be time consuming network traffic and protocol stuff/handshakes involved. Would my instance load a full resultset of "adresses" into the RAM/swap first and then do the JOIN? Or would it be smart enough to tell the linked server: "Hey, look up these IDs and give me back the resulting adresses!" ? (Suppose "adresses" in the linked database has an index on FK_ID)

Suppose "adresses" was in *my* instance and "names" in the linked instance and i would add

```
WHERE names.name='John Smith'
```

to the query, would my instance load a full set of "names", then scan for the matching ID in that heap, and then do an index seek in "adresses"? Or would it be capable to ask the linked database: "Could You find the matching ID for this name for me?" (again: suppose an index on ID was present) and then go to its "adresses" with that?

Basically I'd like to know how smart that optimizer really is (i know: it's smarter than me^^) and whether two optimizers can cooperate in a smart way and come up with a fusioned query plan or somethin', at least on a basic level.

The issue has propably been dealt with/answered/blogged about a multitude of times. Thanks for pointers/links/answers/tricks/workarounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer (which I feel a little guilty about, given the length of your question) is that the optimizer is very aware of information that lives on the server (so Case 1 and Case 2 should have identical plans), but is not so smart about information on the other side.  If you do a JOIN across to a linked server (like server.database.schema.table), you're probably going to end up with a table scan.

Comment: Not much hype about this question^^. Thanks for giving me *something*. And since you basically confirmed what i already guessed: damn. So replicating is the only true fix.

Comment: I'd hesitate to say anything is the "only true fix"; it all depends.  For example, you could work with OPENQUERY to take advantage of indexes on the remote server, or you could redesign your architecture so you don't have a remote server.

Comment: thanks for the tips. i aim to get a runtime optimised solution  that can be run in high frequency. OPENQUERY is interesting to connect to remote sources, need to test it for JOIN across instances. Yet i presume the initiation overhead of such functions and the still missing combined queryplan makes all these no rival to replicating. The linked server is business critical and running on a somewhat fast enough machine. It can be modified to serve as a distributor, but migrating it to something faster and fusioning it with other instances is considered "not funny". It's not a tech company.