# Is there general DB Performance issue JOINING across more than 1 DB on same server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any REAL DB performance issues when you join tables that exist in different tables?  Assume there are 500K+ rows in both?  We debate this at work and no one is definitive in their answer.

Example:

DB A
 TableA:   OrderId INT PK
               Name VARCHAR(40)

DB B
  TableB:  DeliveryId INT PK
           OrderId INT
           Address VARCHAR(50)...

The question is are there issues in GENERAL about querying tables across more than 1 DB....  if the only issues are related to the query and the plan then that means it's no different than any other query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross database queries, joins advantages and disadvantages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062801/cross-database-queries-joins-advantages-and-disadvantages)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the problems with a join between two tables in two different databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144457/what-are-the-problems-with-a-join-between-two-tables-in-two-different-databases)